# Template engine cannot find navigation.ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs, template-engine

[image]

> I get this reference error from ejs. Path not found, meanwhile I have the file in my includes folder. When I change navigation.ejs to a different file (let's say end.ejs) I don't get the error.

[image]

> importing navigation.ejs in the body tag.

[image]

> includes folder.

Answer (score 0):

> The path was not included to the object in the render method. Therefore, when navigated to an unknown URL it errors out.

[image]

It errors out here because the path was not included to the object in the render method.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not correct. You need to move up the directory first:

```
<%- include('./../includes/navigation.ejs') %>
```